# what is the usage of `spl_autoload_extension() `with `spl_autoload_register()`?

Tags: php, function, spl-autoload-register

I am using [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) function to include all files . What i want that any class having extension `.class.php` or `.php` would includes directly. I made below class and register two different function and everything working fine, **BUT**

I think there is some way so that i need to register only one function to include both extensions together.

please have a look on my function and tell me what i am missing

#### my folder structure

```
project
      -classes
           -alpha.class.php
           -beta.class.php
           -otherclass.php
      -includes
           - autoload.php
      -config.inc.php // define CLASS_DIR and include 'autoload.php'
```

#### autoload.php

```
var_dump(__DIR__); // 'D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\includes' 
var_dump(CLASS_DIR); // 'D:/xampp/htdocs/myproject/classes/' 
spl_autoload_register(null, false);
spl_autoload_extensions(".php, .class.php"); // no use for now
/*** class Loader ***/
class AL
{
     public static function autoload($class)
     {
          $filename = strtolower($class) . '.php';
          $filepath = CLASS_DIR.$filename;
          if(is_readable($filepath)){
              include_once $filepath;
          }
//          else {
//                trigger_error("The class file was not found!", E_USER_ERROR);
//            }
    }

    public static function classLoader($class)
    {
        $filename = strtolower($class) . '.class.php';
        $filepath = CLASS_DIR . $filename;
        if(is_readable($filepath)){
              include_once $filepath;
          }
    }

}
spl_autoload_register('AL::autoload');
spl_autoload_register('AL::classLoader');
```

**Note :** there is no effect on line `spl_autoload_extensions();` . why?

i also read [this blog](http://joshosopher.tumblr.com/post/1271596379/the-new-keyword-autoloading-and-namespaces-in-php-5-3) but did not understand how to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the way you do it. Two distinctive autoloaders for two kinds of class files are fine, but I would give them slightly more descriptive names ;)

> Note : there is no effect on line `spl_autoload_extensions();` . why?

This only affects the builtin-autoloading [`spl_autoload()`](http://php.net/spl-autoload).

Maybe it's easier to use a single loader after all

```
 public static function autoload($class)
 {
      if (is_readable(CLASS_DIR.strtolower($class) . '.php')) {
          include_once CLASS_DIR.strtolower($class) . '.php';
      }  else if (is_readable(CLASS_DIR.strtolower($class) . '.class.php')) {
          include_once CLASS_DIR.strtolower($class) . '.class.php';
      }
}
```

You may also omit the whole class

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    if (is_readable(CLASS_DIR.strtolower($class) . '.php')) {
        include_once CLASS_DIR.strtolower($class) . '.php';
    }  else if (is_readable(CLASS_DIR.strtolower($class) . '.class.php')) {
        include_once CLASS_DIR.strtolower($class) . '.class.php';
    }
});
```

Comment: because if i comment that line , there is no error/effects on project.
 will you please suggest me that descriptive names?

Comment: Just re-read the question and realized, that the _only_ difference is the extension. OK, maybe it's easier to use a single loader in this case ;) I've updated my answer. However, a descriptive name ... describes what happens :D For example like `PSR0Loader::loadClass()` (referencing the PSR0-style class-to-filename-mapping) or such. Don't know, I'm not very good in finding appropiate names too

Comment: thanks for the help. but there is no way to do it with `spl_autoload_extension()`

Comment: As mentioned it only affects `spl_autoload()`. You can try it out, if it's already sufficient for your: `spl_extensiom('.php,.class.php');spl_autoloader_register(/* no argument*/);`

Comment: `else if (is_readable(CLASS_DIR.strtolower($class) . '.php')) {` should be `else if (is_readable(CLASS_DIR.strtolower($class) . '.class.php')) {` isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:

http://php.net/manual/de/function.spl-autoload-extensions.php

> Jeremy Cook 03-Sep-2010 06:46
>
> A quick note for anyone using this function to add their own autoload
>   extensions. I found that if I included a space in between the
>   different extensions (i.e. '.php, .class.php') the function would not
>   work. To get it to work I had to remove the spaces between the
>   extensions (ie. '.php,.class.php'). This was tested in PHP 5.3.3 on
>   Windows and I'm using spl_autoload_register() without adding any
>   custom autoload functions.
>
> Hope that helps somebody.

Comment: I have take care of these things already.everything working fine . i just want to optimize that class